# cnlp_annotate does not return fields from meta dataframe in R

Tags: r, nlp

I'm working with the `cleanNLP` package, but `cnlp_get_annotate` does not return tags from meta dataframe argument in R. The rest of the annotation function works.

```
library(sotu)

data(sotu_meta)

cnlp_init_spacy(vector_flag = TRUE)

sotu_text <- sotu_text[1:5]

sotu_meta <- sotu_meta[1:5,]

sotu <- cnlp_annotate(sotu_text, as_strings = TRUE, meta = sotu_meta)

cnlp_get_document(sotu)

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  id    time                 version language       uri                          
  <chr> <chr>                <chr>   <chr>          <chr>                        
1 doc1  2018-05-30 22:09:23Z 2.0.11  en_core_web_sm "C:\\Users\\VIVEK~1.SIN\\App~
2 doc2  2018-05-30 22:09:24Z 2.0.11  en_core_web_sm "C:\\Users\\VIVEK~1.SIN\\App~
3 doc3  2018-05-30 22:09:26Z 2.0.11  en_core_web_sm "C:\\Users\\VIVEK~1.SIN\\App~
4 doc4  2018-05-30 22:09:28Z 2.0.11  en_core_web_sm "C:\\Users\\VIVEK~1.SIN\\App~
5 doc5  2018-05-30 22:09:29Z 2.0.11  en_core_web_sm "C:\\Users\\VIVEK~1.SIN\\App~
```